# how to ignore files that are already tracked in git

Tags: git, version-control, github

I tried to `pull origin a`.

and go the following:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    src/.cproject
    src/.project
    src/navigate/navigate_main.c
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

git status showed:

```
    modified:   .gitignore
modified:   src/.cproject
modified:   src/.project
modified:   src/navigate/navigate_main.c
```

I did `git rm --cached src/.project` to the first 3, and `stashed` the 4th

I did pull again and unstashed my changes.

however when I do `pull origin a`

I get:

```
M   .gitignore
U   src/.cproject
M   src/navigate/navigate_main.c
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

how can I clean this once and for all?

Comment: You have modified files, which differ from their counterparts on server.First merge those files.then Commit. then pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `git rm --cached src/.project` doesn't do much good unless you `commit` the change. Why not just `git stash` everything, then `pull`, `stash pop`, and then remove the ignored files with `rm --cached`?

Comment: I alway have merge conflict on `.cproject` because my eclipse project is named differently than my colleague's. Each of us started with a different name, that's why our project are named differently.

Comment: You're going to save yourself a lot of headache if you unify your dev environment with your collaborators.

Answer (score 0):

Uncommitted changes are always bad. You have to decide whether those changes are good or bad. If they are good, commit them. If the are bad, discard them.

Once you have no more uncommitted changes you have no more problems.

Have a look at `git status` or `git status --short` to see any uncommitted changes.

Configure a meaningful prompt to see what is going on immediately.
For bash add something like this to your ~/.bashrc:

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=yes
GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=yes
GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=yes
GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM=auto
```