# Why does git insist on "Everything up-to-date" although there are two files that are not pushed

Tags: git

I have changed two files, added and commited the changes. Now, I'd like to push my changes. Git, however, tells me `Everything up-to-date`.

Yet, the output of `git diff --stat origin/master` is

```
development/hewc/readme.txt |  1 +
development/mul/readme.txt  | 16 +++++++++++++++-
2 files changed, 16 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

which (as I take it) means that there should indeed be something pushed.

Comment: git status?what it says?

Comment: What command gives you this output? `git push`? What is an output of `git remote`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have uncommitted changes. First commit them, then you can push them. :)

If you do not commit them, git does not know anything about them. Therefore your local master still equals the remote master and git concludes that everything is up-to-date.

Comment: Well, I was **100%** sure that I commited those changes.... and I only tried to commit them to tell you that I have already commited them. Turns out I have not commited them.

Comment: Having a good shell prompt might help you with that. For bash see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18300685/1870481

Answer (score 0):

You have changes that have been added but not committed.

The git cycle goes:

- make changes and/or create new files
- **add** the changes and/or files

*the above can be done several times*

- **commit** - this groups all the changes added since the last commit into a single event.

*the above can be done several times*

- **push** (or request pull) - this shares the changes out to the world.